# Why would testing summer and winter solstice matter?

Tags: test-design, test-data, date

On [Ministry of Testing](https://www.ministryoftesting.com/dojo/lessons/checklist-for-testing-web-page-functionality) site there is the **Checklist for Testing Web Page Functionality**.

In **Date & Time** section, there is a "Summer and winter solstice (26: e mars kl 02-03 and 29: e October 02-03)" checkbox.

Why would those dates matter? I'm not aware anything changes in way calendars handle time. Are there local calendars that take those days in consideration?

Comment: Those _aren't_ the summer and winter solstices, they're closer to the equinoxes. But then immediate thing that jumps out about them, from a UK perspective at least, is: that's round about when the clocks change (in our case between GMT and BST).

Comment: I suspect (hence not an answer) that this is a bug and they meant summer-winter time. (Whomever downvoted this please explain why)

Comment: The key thing about the _actual_ solstices is they're the longest and shortest day/night, so if you were doing something related to daylight hours, sunrise/sunset, etc. that might be worth considering. But it seems pointless to speculate why some third party decided that was important.

Comment: I thought that was about the daylight savings time, but it is not clear from their wording. I'm guessing the 'mars' is March so they are actually saying last weekend of March and last weekend of October.

Comment: "Mars" is Swedish for "March", yes. For Central European Time, the times mentioned are exactly the ones that were affected by the switch to DST in 2017, i.e. did not exist or happened twice. ("Kl" as an abbreviation in Swedish more or less corresponds to "o'clock".)

Comment: As said, I think this is more of a long/short day issue with clock change days in March and October.